# Calculus on last 'n' ForeignKey of a Model Django way (annotate/aggregate)?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

Here is my problem: I got two models: FieldPlayer (It represent a Sport session with different values like report_id, scores, average speed etc.) and Player (Player who can perform multiples sessions, he got a name, a team and a league).

Here are theses models in my code:

```
class FieldPlayer(models.Model):
  """                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
  Represent the performance of a player on a game.                                                                                                                                                                                             
  Has an owner and a remote report url.                                                                                                                                                                                                        
  """
  owner = models.ForeignKey(Player, related_name='performances')
  report_id = models.IntegerField(null=True)
  date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
  distance = models.FloatField(default=0)
  pace = models.FloatField(default=0)
  training_length = models.FloatField(default=0)
  running_time_ratio = models.FloatField(default=0)
  h_i_average_speed = models.FloatField(default=0)
  h_i_run_time = models.FloatField(default=0)
  explosivity = models.FloatField(default=0)
  run_number = models.IntegerField(default=0)
  overview = JSONField(null=True, blank=True) # Deprecated                                                                                                                                                                                     
  game = models.ForeignKey(
    Game, null=True, blank=True, related_name='players')
  was_home = models.BooleanField(default=True)
  speed_score = models.IntegerField(default=0)
  stamina_score = models.IntegerField(default=0)
  activity_score = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

My Player model:

```
class Player(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
  picture = ThumbnailerImageField(
    upload_to='profile_pictures', resize_source={'size': (200, 200),
  'crop': 'smart'}, blank=True, null=True)
  team = models.ForeignKey(
    Team, null=True, blank=True, related_name='players')
  # TODO: Replace with db model instead of static string                                                                                                                                                                                       
  league = {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Champigny - Elite",
    "logo": None
  }
  average_speed_score = models.IntegerField(default=0)
  average_stamina_score = models.IntegerField(default=0)
  average_activity_score = models.IntegerField(default=0)
  score = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

I need to get the following values to display for my "Player-detail" view:

- Average speed_score of the Player for the last 5 Sessions (Sessions = FieldPlayers instances)
- Average stamina_score of the Player for the last 5 Sessions.
- Average activity_score of the Player for the last 5 Sessions.
- Score value = Average of all the 3 above scores.
- All the 'report_id' values in an Array for the last 5 Sessions.

In fact, I'm already able to compute all these but programmatically. For example, to get all the recent reports_ids I did theses methods in my Player Model:

```
def get_n_last_sessions(self, n):
  return self.performances.all()[:n]

def recents_reports(self):
  sessions_list = self.get_n_last_sessions(5)
  reports_ids = []
  for sessions in  sessions_list:
    reports_ids.append(sessions.report_id)
  return reports_ids
```

I can do the same for all the compute I need. But is this a good way to achieve this ? I don't think so but If i'm wrong, please tell me.

So here is the true problem: How to achieve this kind of computing with Django `annotate` or `aggregate` way ? Is this even possible and/or good practice ?

I'm totally new to Django and Python.

Comment: How do you want to get an "average speed_score of the Player for the last 5 Sessions" if `speed_score` is recorded in the `Player` model and not the `FieldPlayer` (session) model?

Comment: It was a Copy/Paste mistake, there is score properties in both actually. Edited

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking for these values as properties or functions on your model then:

```
from django.db.models import Avg


class Player(models.Model):
    ....

    ....
    @property
    def average_speed_score(self):
        return self.performances.order_by('-date')[:5].aggregate(Avg('speed_score'))

    @property
    def average_stamina_score(self):
        return self.performances.order_by('-date')[:5].aggregate(Avg('stamina_score'))

    @property
    def average_activity_score(self):
        return self.performances.order_by('-date')[:5].aggregate(Avg('activity_score'))

    @property
    def score(self):
        return sum([self.average_speed_score, average_stamina_score, self.average_activity_score])/3

    def return_last_n_report_ids(self, n):
        return self.performances.objects.order_by('-date')[:n].values_list('report_id', flat=True)
```

You can learn about the `@property` decorator [here](http://www.programiz.com/python-programming/property), `.aggregate` in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/aggregation/), and `values_list` in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#values-list) as well.

EDIT: Okay, updated from clarification in comment :)

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion I just updated my question. `speed_score`, `stamina_score` and `activity_score` are actually stored in FieldPlayer Model.

The `average_speed_score` for exemple, have to be the Average of the last 5 FieldPlayers `speed_score` (a Player can be related to many FieldPlayer, cf. ForeignKey).

But I also need a list of the `report_id` correspounding to the last 5 FieldPlayers.

Comment: Ah, I see, I updated my answer to add a function that returns the report ids

Comment: Your answer and Ludwik's one are both fine. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

You can easily retrieve information described in the first four of your points in a single (!) database query. Just limit the queryset to 5 elements (`[:5]`) and perform approperiate aggregations:

```
from django.db.models import Avg

FieldPlayer.objects.filter(player=player).order_by('-date')[:5].aggregate(
    avg_speed_score=Avg('speed_score'),
    avg_stamina_score=Avg('stamina_score'),
    avg_activity_score=Avg('activity_score'),
    avg_all=(Avg('speed_score')+Avg('stamina_score')+Avg('activity_score'))/3,
)
```

`player` is the current `Player` object.

The last point is a little different. This isn't an aggregation like the ones above, so I think you would have to perform a second query for this:

```
FieldPlayer.objects.filter(player=player) \
    .order_by('-pk')[:5].values_list('report_id', flat=True)
```

This would get you a list of all the `report_id` values for the last 5 sessions.

Comment: Thanks for answering this seems to be exactly what I'm looking for.

Where do I put the FieldPlayer.objects.filter ? On my ViewSet/Serializer ? What's the best practice ?

Comment: You can either put it in your ViewSet or make a method on the `Player` object if you think you might want to reuse the information in other views.